# Permanently fixing a variable in the function

Tags: functions, core-language

I need to define a function let's say `f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2` such that I need to fix one variable (let's take `y = a`) and to evaluate the expression which would now be in terms of  only the other variable and the fixed variable. So, for input like `f[x1, y1]`, the output must be `x1^2 + a^2`. For input `f[x2, y2]`, the corresponding output must be `x2^2 + a^2` .

Comment: P.S.: I have just started using mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: So why do you even need second argument?

Comment: How about defining a new function which is "f with y set to a": `fya[x_] := f[x, a]`

Comment: @bills I am generally against such constructs, since they add a dependence on a global variable, in a way that is hard to control, and then it leads to [all sorts of troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808). I think, in such cases it is better to either use `SubValues`: `fya[a_][x_]:=f[x,a]` (so that then one always uses `fya[a]` as a "function"), or create a closure at run-time: `makeFYA[a_]:= Function[x,f[x,a]]`, and then `fya = makeFYA[a]`. The advantage here is that we have a better control.

Answer (score 1):

You could define `y` to be an optional argument which will get the default value `a` when no value for `y` is supplied.

```
 f[x_, y_: a] := x^2 + y^2

 {f[u, v], f[u]}
```

> ```
> {u^2 + v^2, a^2 + u^2}
> ```